# Window function error At least 1 group must only depend on input columns

Tags: sql, hiveql

I have a common table expression with a window function and keep getting an error message:

> Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException Failed to
>   breakup Windowing invocations into Groups. At least 1 group must only
>   depend on input columns. Also check for circular dependencies.
>   Underlying error: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.SemanticException:
>   Line 82:6 Invalid column reference 'gcr_amt' in definition of CTE
>   pro_orders [ select o.shopper_id as pro_shopper_id,
>   date_format(o.order_date, 'YYYYMM') as ym_order, sum(o.gcr_amt) as
>   total_gcr, sum(case when o.product_pnl_new_renewal_name = 'New
>   Purchase' then o.gcr_amt end) as new_gcr, sum(o.gcr_amt) over
>   (partition by o.shopper_id rows between 12 preceding and 1 following)
>   as 12months_direct_gcr from dp_enterprise.uds_order o inner join
>   combined_shopper_level_data cs on cs.pro_shopper_id = o.shopper_id and
>   cs.year_month = date_format(o.order_date, 'YYYYMM') where
>   o.exclude_reason_desc is Null group by o.shopper_id, o.order_date ]
>   used as po at Line 83:5

My cte looks like this:

```
pro_orders as (
  select  o.shopper_id as pro_shopper_id,
          date_format(o.order_date, 'YYYYMM') as ym_order,
          sum(o.gcr_amt) as total_gcr,
          sum(case when o.product_pnl_new_renewal_name = 'New Purchase' then o.gcr_amt end) as new_gcr,
          sum(o.gcr_amt) over (partition by o.shopper_id, cs.year_month order by cs.year_month desc rows between 12 preceding and 0 following) as 12months_direct_gcr
  from dp_enterprise.uds_order o
  right join combined_shopper_level_data cs on cs.pro_shopper_id = o.shopper_id and cs.year_month = date_format(o.order_date, 'YYYYMM')
  group by o.shopper_id, o.order_date
),
```

I don't use window functions that often and perhaps my syntax is off. In english what I'm trying to do is get the 12 months total for metric "gcr".

So a row with shopper_id 123abc in year_month 201901, I'd like to sum the preceding 11 months plus the current rows month of gcr for a total of 12 months. Not sure if my window function is correctly set up for that or not?

The format of year_month being referenced is YYYYMM e.g. 201901.

Is my window function set up right given my goal?

How can I overcome this error message?

Edit:
Still receiving this error message with the following CTE:

```
pro_orders as (
  select  o.shopper_id as pro_shopper_id,
          cs.year_month,
          sum(case when date_format(o.order_date, 'YYYYMM') = cs.year_month then o.gcr_amt else 0 end) as total_gcr,
          sum(case when date_format(o.order_date, 'YYYYMM') = cs.year_month and o.product_pnl_new_renewal_name = 'New Purchase' then o.gcr_amt else 0 end) as new_gcr,
          sum(sum(o.gcr_amt)) over  (partition by o.shopper_id 
                                order by cs.year_month desc 
                                rows between 12 preceding and 0 following) 
                                as 12months_direct_gcr
  from combined_shopper_level_data cs
  left join dp_enterprise.uds_order o on o.shopper_id = cs.pro_shopper_id
  where o.exclude_reason_desc is Null
  group by o.shopper_id, cs.year_month
),
```

Results in similar error message:

> Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException Failed to
>   breakup Windowing invocations into Groups. At least 1 group must only
>   depend on input columns. Also check for circular dependencies.
>   Underlying error: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.SemanticException:
>   Line 83:10 Invalid column reference 'gcr_amt' in definition of CTE
>   pro_orders [ select o.shopper_id as pro_shopper_id, cs.year_month,
>   sum(case when date_format(o.order_date, 'YYYYMM') = cs.year_month then
>   o.gcr_amt else 0 end) as total_gcr, sum(case when
>   date_format(o.order_date, 'YYYYMM') = cs.year_month and
>   o.product_pnl_new_renewal_name = 'New Purchase' then o.gcr_amt else 0
>   end) as new_gcr, sum(sum(o.gcr_amt)) over (partition by o.shopper_id
>   order by cs.year_month desc rows between 12 preceding and 0 following)
>   as 12months_direct_gcr from combined_shopper_level_data cs left join
>   dp_enterprise.uds_order o on o.shopper_id = cs.pro_shopper_id where
>   o.exclude_reason_desc is Null group by o.shopper_id, cs.year_month ]
>   used as po at Line 87:5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an aggregation query, so the window function looks a little funny.  The basic idea is something like this:

```
sum(sum(o.gcr_amt)) over (partition by o.shopper_id, cs.year_month
                          order by cs.year_month desc
                          rows between 12 preceding and 0 following
                         ) as 12months_direct_gcr
```

This still will not work.  First, you have the value in the `order by` and `partition by`.  Second, it is not in the `group by`.

Assuming there is a value for each month, then you can use:

```
sum(sum(o.gcr_amt)) over (partition by o.shopper_id
                          order by cs.year_month desc
                          rows between 12 preceding and 0 following
                         ) as 12months_direct_gcr
```

And use `cs.year_month` in the `group by` (which may require adjusting other parts of the query.

For readability, I also recommend that you use `left join` rather than `right join`.  For me (and most people), it is much simpler cognitively to say "keep all the rows in the first table I just read" rather than "keep all the rows in some table I'm going to read at the end of the `from` clause".

EDIT:

I think the full query is:

```
with pro_orders as (
      select o.shopper_id as pro_shopper_id,
             cs.year_month,
             sum(coalesce(o.gcr_amt, 0)) as total_gcr,
             sum(case when o.product_pnl_new_renewal_name = 'New Purchase' then o.gcr_amt else 0 end) as new_gcr,
             sum(sum(o.gcr_amt)) over (partition by o.shopper_id 
                                       order by cs.year_month desc 
                                       rows between 12 preceding and 0 following
                                      ) as 12months_direct_gcr
      from combined_shopper_level_data cs left join
           dp_enterprise.uds_order o
           on o.shopper_id = cs.pro_shopper_id and
              date_format(o.order_date, 'YYYYMM') = cs.year_month and
              o.exclude_reason_desc is Null
      group by o.shopper_id, cs.year_month
     ),
```

It is possible that there is a limitation in Hive on using window functions in aggregation queries (this would sort of surprise me, because these are processed separately).  I can't find a specific reference to this.  If so, just use a subquery:

```
with pro_orders as (
      select pro_shopper_id, year_month, total_gcr, new_gcr
             sum(sum(total_gcr_amt)) over (partition by pro_shopper_id
                                           order by year_month desc 
                                           rows between 12 preceding and 0 following
                                          ) as 12months_direct_gcr
      from (select o.shopper_id as pro_shopper_id,
                   cs.year_month,
                   sum(coalesce(o.gcr_amt, 0)) as total_gcr,
                   sum(case when o.product_pnl_new_renewal_name = 'New Purchase' then o.gcr_amt else 0 end) as new_gcr,
          from combined_shopper_level_data cs left join
               dp_enterprise.uds_order o
               on o.shopper_id = cs.pro_shopper_id and
                  date_format(o.order_date, 'YYYYMM') = cs.year_month and
                  o.exclude_reason_desc is Null
          group by o.shopper_id, cs.year_month
         ) ps
     ),
```

Comment: Just wanted to verify, the double nesting of sum is correct and not typo? ```sum(sum(o.gcr_amt))```

Comment: Hm. Also still struggling with this one. I added my updated CTE to the bottom of my post, does anything still look off with this?

Comment: @DougFir . . . The windows function is executed *after* the aggregation.  Hence, only columns and expressions available *after* the aggregation are available.

Comment: Thanks for the info Gordon. Does that mean that I should reference the new field name "total_gcr" as opposed to the input field name 'gcr_amt"? Since after the query aggregates the field will be called total_gcr?

Comment: @DougFir . . . Most databases don't let you do that.  I don't remember if Hive does (I haven't used Hive in a while and I remember it has funky rules regarding column aliases).

Comment: Thanks again for the info here. Does anything seem a miss in my updated CTE at the bottom of my post? Really struggling with this one

Comment: @DougFir . . . This may depend on the version of Hive you are using.  I found this reference "Aggregate functions in OVER clause support in Hive 2.1.0 and later (see HIVE-13475)".  That suggests that you might need a subquery in an older version.